# Computing proportion of each unqiue label

Tags: pandas, numpy

I am trying to compute the normalized range associated with each unique label in a list. In the example below, the label `'A'` is proportionate to the first 37.5 % of all labels, `'B'` is proportionate to the following 12.5 % of the labels, and so on.

The example:

```
labels = np.array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'E', 'E', 'D'])
```

desired output:

```
[0.0, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.875, 1.0]
```

One may also think of it as dividing an axis into smaller parts:

```
    A     A     A     C     B     E     E     D
0.0 -------------------------------------------- 1.0
    |              |     |     |           |   |
   0.0          0.375   0.5  0.625      0.875 1.0
```

As a follow-up task I need to get the in-between values also:

```
[0.1875, 0.4375, 0.5625, 0.75, 0.9375]
```

Is there a nice way to do this in numpy/pandas without loopy code?

Answer (score 1):

Check with `value_counts` then `cumsum` calculate sum for each label , then we do `rolling`

```
s = pd.Series(labels)
out = pd.Series(0).append(s.value_counts(normalize=True).reindex(s.unique()).cumsum()).rolling(2,min_periods=1).mean().iloc[1:]
Out[68]: 
A    0.1875
C    0.4375
B    0.5625
E    0.7500
D    0.9375
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thanks, the first 2 values are correct. Trying to get the output `[0.0, 0.375, 0.5, 0.625, 0.875, 1.0]` :)

Comment: The following seems to work: `s.value_counts(normalize=True, sort=False).cumsum()`

Comment: @Kevin check the update